# Why the comma in "I received a gift from Uncle George, but not from my other uncle"?

Tags: conjunctions, punctuation, commas, clauses, subordinate-clauses

As far as I understand it, "But not from my other uncle" is not an independent clause. It could show contrast, but that would still require an independent clause, like "John is rich, but Mary is poor", or wouldn't it?

Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you're correct in both "but not from my other uncle" not being an independent clause and 'but' showing contrast connecting the two clauses, though a dependent clause after an independent clause can have a comma when a contrast word follows up the independent clause (In this case the coordinating conjunction "but" shows it). Native speakers, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @SorryI'mDumb, Makes me want to contemplate it in this way: "I received a gift from Uncle George, but I haven't received a gift from my other uncle". But then that would make some kind of a "predicate" junction structure which doesn't need a comma. Confusing.

Comment: This website might help in some way, https://www.savvy-strategies.com/blog/2019/12/5/how-to-combine-sentences

Comment: The comma is an error. It should not be there.  But is a conjunction.